# Store object as a draft

Tags: iphone, core-data, storage

What is the best way to store some objects as a "Draft". I have a form which one can fill out and than press Save. This should upload the data to the internet. But if the user is offline I would like to save it as a draft so the user can upload it later.

Any best practices? Objects can be images, textfields or ManagedObjects from CoreData.

Answer (score 1):

Save it to CoreData with an ID, and store this ID in `NSUserDefaults` when opening the application next time, check if `NSUserDefaults` has any IDs, if there is then save to the cloud, otherwise keep the ID in UserDefaults.

Any ID that is stored to cloud then remove from `NSUserDefaults`

Answer (score 1):

[`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is probably the most efficient place for this kind of task:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:YourObject forKey:@"Draft1"]
```

Depending on your object(s) you might want to either save more or less values to the userdefaults.

Comment: If the object contains photos, managedobject and other stuff, then it will be large for the `UserDefaults`, which is only an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: NSUserDefaults are only limited to the currently available free memory you have.

The general expectation is, that the draft objects get pruned once the task is completed - thus freeing the memory.